# preg_replace regex not working as expected

Tags: php, regex

So i'm trying to do the following and it's not working. not sure why:

```
$block = preg_replace('#\{([A-Z0-9\-_]+)\}#', "<?php " . $this->compile_var(\\1) . " ?>", $block);
```

What i'm using that for is to turn this input:

```
<link href="{VAR_TEMPLATE_PATH}css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

into:

```
 <link href="<?php $this->page_vars["TEMPLATE_PATH"] ?>css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

The actual conversion is fine, thats all contained in compile_var, but preg_replace is no longer turning \\1 into "VAR_TEMPLATE_PATH", which is used to do when inside a string.

Instead it is passing "\1" as the argument for compile_var?

Why is this happening all of a sudden? and how can i fix it?

Cheers!

Comment: Try \1 instead of \\1?

Answer (score 1):

Use it like this:

```
$block = '<link href="{VAR_TEMPLATE_PATH}css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">';
$block=preg_replace('#\{(?:VAR_)?([\w-]+)\}#', '<?php $this->compile_var("\1") ?>', $block);
echo $block;
```

#### OUTPUT:

```
<link href="<?php $this->compile_var("TEMPLATE_PATH") ?>css/common.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

If you want `VAR_` also in final output then use:

```
$block = preg_replace('#\{([\w-]+)\}#', '<?php $this->compile_var("\1") ?>', $block);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using `\1` in compile_var instead.

`<?php " . $this->compile_var(\1) . " ?>`

Here's a working example: http://regex101.com/r/rM0jD1

Comment: That just throws a syntax error:
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '\' (T_NS_SEPARATOR), expecting identifier (T_STRING) in